# psycopg2 ERROR: not all arguments converted during string formatting on line number: 46 when perform a SELECT count statement

Tags: python, postgresql, psycopg2

I'm trying to count the occurrences in a postgreSQL table which contains only one "IPaddress" column.

I do the insertion like this:

```
query = """SELECT COUNT (*) FROM public." hostSeen "WHERE" IPaddress "= (% s);"""

connectionParameters [1] .execute (query, str (hostIP))
```

That even seeing answers to similar problems online seems correct to me.

However, the operation fails and outputs the error in question.

Do you have any ideas?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Simply adjust quotes and spaces and pass param as tuple/list: `query = 'SELECT COUNT(*) FROM public."hostSeen" WHERE "IPaddress" = %s'` and `connectionParameters[1].execute(query, (str(hostIP),))`.

Comment: But why you write (str(hostIP),)? I don't understand this.

Comment: That's a one item tuple. Alternatively, use a list: `[str(hostIP)]`.